# Construct list of numbers of occurrences in list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I am given a list of elements such as

```
[1,1,2,3,3,1,2]
```

or

```
["a","a","b","c","c"]
```

Given such a list, I would like to construct a (not necessarily ordered) list containing the number of occurrences of each element. For instance, the first list should return

```
[3,2,2]
```

as there are 3 ones, 2 twos, and 3 threes in the list. The second should similarly return

```
[2,1,2]
```

What is the best way to go about this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> construct a (**not necessarily ordered**) list containing the number of occurrences of each element

Since you are not worried about the order, you can simply use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), like this

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2]).values()
[3, 2, 2]
>>> Counter(["a", "a", "b", "c", "c"]).values()
[2, 2, 1]
```

The `Counter` object is nothing but a dictionary, with the keys found in the iterable and the values will be the actual number of times the corresponding key found in the iterable. You can print the `Counter` object and check that, like this

```
>>> Counter([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2])
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2})
>>> Counter(["a", "a", "b", "c", "c"])
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 1})
```

Since you are interested only in the number of times of occurrences, we are taking only the `values()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.count`,within a list comprehension but note that you may use `set` for checking the membership as its more efficient for this aim  :

```
>>> l=[1,1,2,3,3,1,2]
>>> [l.count(i) for i in set(l)]
[3, 2, 2]
```

As you can see in the following bench mark, using this recipe is **7 time faster**:

```
:~$ python -m timeit "l=[1,1,2,3,3,1,2];[l.count(i) for i in set(l)]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.718 usec per loop
:~$ python -m timeit "l=[1,1,2,3,3,1,2];[l.count(i) for i in l]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.97 usec per loop
:~$ python -m timeit "l=[1,1,2,3,3,1,2];from collections import Counter;Counter([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2]).values()"
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.27 usec per loop
```

Comment: From the OP's first example, it's obvious `groupby` doesn't fit their needs.

Answer (score 1):

Best to create dictionary (key-value) to have every unique value as key and its occurrence in the given list.

```
>>> l
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2]
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.Counter(l)
>>> print d
Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2})
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In 'pure' Python:

```
x = [1,1,2,3,3,1,2]
y = [x.count(u) for u in set(x)]
>>> y
[3, 2, 2]
```

In the spirit of Kasra's benchmark, using the simple list comprehension is twice as fast as the next solution, although there is probably some overhead in the module import in the first three methods:

```
>>> print ' first: ' ,timeit(stmt=s1, number=100000)
 first:  0.358644798424
>>> print ' second: ' ,timeit(stmt=s2, number=100000)
 second:  0.466576073569
>>> print ' third: ' ,timeit(stmt=s3, number=100000)
 third:  0.685125215535
>>> print ' fourth: ' ,timeit(stmt=s4, number=100000)
 fourth:  0.143517940718
```